# Moving live wordpress site to MAMP server? Error : Website not available

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I have followed all steps while moving website to MAMP server manually.

Changed the url also.

It still says website not available when I open the localhost link.

Wp-admin page also not opening.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have Mamp pointing to the project folder?  Did you export/import your WP database? Do you have Mamp running?  Do you see the Mamp start page?  There are so many possible reasons... you might need to provide a bit more info.

Comment: Yes .. I imported the WP Database. I have MAMP Running. Yes i see the Mamp Running. I have copied the wp-content folder. I have changed the wp-config file.

Comment: I have also run 3 queries to change my URL to localhost.. Then also it shows website not available.

Comment: *"I have followed all steps"*, and which would be those? . . . I never had much problems with moving Live->Mamp and alway use this script [WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its mamp pro, just do this:
1. copy the whole folder of wordpress to the htdocs
2. export the db from your online server and import to the local phpymyadmin
3. go to wp-config.php of the local wordpress you copied and put username: root and password: root
4. go to mamp home, add new host, put your domain name and assign the folder for it.
5. restart mamp.

NOTE: do NOT change the URL at all of wordrpress, not on DB and not in the admin page. It will deal with the website is its online.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRMt5.png)